# Hibernate6.2-JPA: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for <Custom class>

Tags: hibernate-native-query, hibernate-jpa

I am using Java 17 with spring boot version 3.1.0, Hibernate 6.2.2.Final & postgresql 12.
Running into "Could not determine recommended JdbcType for" error when inserting the data into jsonb column's using **native query**. We have specific req to batch insert using native query.

error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfuDm.png)

jdbc type error

Tried using hibernate provided annotations with @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
and hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62 annotations with @Type(JsonType.class) on both jsonb
properties expn & expnScratch

1. Using hypersistence-utils @Type(JsonType.class) on properties

```
  @Type(JsonType.class)
  @Column(columnDefinition="jsonb")
  private EnrichExpn expn;

  @Type(JsonType.class)
  @Column(columnDefinition="jsonb")
  private EnrichExpnScratch expnScratch;

  Native query :
  String query = "INSERT INTO cust_enrich(cust_id, correlation_id, expn, expn_scratch)                     
  values(:cust_id, :correlation_id, :expn, :expn_scratch) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING "

  var queryRun =
          entityManager
              .createNativeQuery(query)
              .unwrap(Query.class)
              .setParameter("cust_id", t.getCustId())
              .setParameter("correlation_id", t.getCorrelationId())
              .setParameter("expn", t.getExpn(), JsonType.INSTANCE)
              .setParameter("expn_scratch", t.getExpnScratch(), JsonType.INSTANCE);
queryRun.executeUpdate();
```

2. Using Hibernate @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)

```
  @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
  @Column(columnDefinition="jsonb")
  private EnrichExpn expn;

  @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
  @Column(columnDefinition="jsonb")
  private EnrichExpnScratch expnScratch;

Native query :
String query = "INSERT INTO cust_enrich(cust_id, correlation_id, expn, expn_scratch)                 values(:cust_id, :correlation_id, :expn, :expn_scratch) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING "

var queryRun =
          entityManager
              .createNativeQuery(query)
              .unwrap(Query.class)
              .setParameter("cust_id", t.getCustId())
              .setParameter("correlation_id", t.getCorrelationId())
              .setParameter("expn", t.getExpn(), SqlType.class)
              .setParameter("expn_scratch", t.getExpnScratch(), SqlType.class);
queryRun.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hypersistence-utils @Type(JsonType.class) on properties worked. Need to call JsonType constructor with class type as shown below. Suggested by vladmihalcea himself [test case](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/blob/master/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62/src/test/java/io/hypersistence/utils/hibernate/type/json/generic/GenericPostgreSQLJsonTypeTest.java#L107)

new JsonType(Expn.class) & new JsonType(ExpnScratch.class).

```
var queryRun =
      entityManager
          .createNativeQuery(query)
          .unwrap(Query.class)
          .setParameter("cust_id", t.getCustId())
          .setParameter("correlation_id", t.getCorrelationId())
          .setParameter("expn", t.getExpn(), new JsonType(Expn.class))
          .setParameter("expn_scratch", t.getExpnScratch(), new JsonType(ExpnScratch.class));
```